# 24 salsa dancers attend a lesson. There are 10 leaders, 14 followers. They choose 6 leaders, 6 followers and pair them randomly.

Tags: probability

24 salsa enthusiasts attend a lesson. There are 10 leaders and 14 followers. To demonstrate a step, the instructor chooses 6 leaders and 6 followers and pairs  them randomly. How many distinct outcomes are possible?

Since there is a total 24 dancers, would we have $\frac{24!}{6!6!}$?

Comment: Why? Try to describe the "story" behind the formula.

Comment: So in general there are $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ ways to select a group of k from n possibilities.

Comment: But you are not selecting a group here. You are selecting several groups and also match them.

Comment: I'm thrown off by the 10 leaders, and 14 followers being split randomly into 6 and 6

Answer (score 2):

A good method to count the number of ways is to think of a good "story" or a "protocol to conduct the experiment", which has some steps (each easily countable) and accounts for all options. Here are two.

**Option 1** You need to choose 6 leaders and then 6 followers. Then you need to match them, so you can line up the leaders (no matter how). Each permutation of the followers in front of them creates a new pairing. The corresponding number of ways is
$${10 \choose 6}{14 \choose 6}6!$$

**Option 2** You form two lines one in front of the other - leaders and followers. The 6 leftmost leaders and 6 leftmost followers are matched. There are $10!$ ways to permute the leaders and $14!$ the followers. However, permuting the people not selected (not in the 6 leftmost places) doesn't matter so we need to divide by these extra arrangements. In addition, permuting the pairs TOGETHER does not matter because it doesn't change the pairing, so we need to account for that too ($6!$):
$$\tfrac{14! 10!}{8!4!6!}$$

Comment: Thanks. This is what happens when the word is close, but not close enough in the eyes of the autocorrect...